# Bootstrap - how to center a div from right left top and bottom?

Tags: css, responsive-images

Using Bootstrap - how can I center a div from right, left, top, and bottom, plus be able to make picture responsive?
I tried this:

```
#logo{
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
    margin-top: -100px; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your height*/
    margin-left: -250px; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your width*/
}
```

But it disabled the img-responsive.
Is there is any solution to make them both work?

Comment: Please include your html...

Comment: <div class="container">
 
  <div class="row">
   <div id="logo">
   <img src="img/logo.png" width="500px" class="img-responsive"/>
   </div>
 
   </div>
 </div>

Comment: Please edit your question with the HTML you provided.  If you are able a jsfiddle is the most appropriate place to work with your question code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's solution

```
#logo{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 500px;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```